# Send shell command over XMPP, NodeJS

Tags: node.js, shell, xmpp

I have written an XMPP client with NodeJS and "simple-xmpp": it waits for messages sent from another XMPP client, read the messages and, if these are shell commands, execute them.

For example, if Client A send the message: "./run_myscript.sh" to Client B then Client B will run the script ./run_myscript.sh, very simple.

Sending "run" over XMPP works well (the script starts) but sending "stop" (to kill the script) seems to have no effect! The script keeps running.

To study the problem I also add a "test" reply to client A in order to see if the entire communication is broken and it seems so: replies from B to A seems not received!
Why?

Here the section when Client B analyze received messages:

```
xmpp.on('chat', function(from, message) { 
var msg = message.toString();
if(msg === 'run'){           //if the message is "run"...
    var cmd = require('child_process').execSync('./run.sh').exec; //run the script

}else if(msg === 'stop'){    //if the message is "stop"...   
    var cmd = require('child_process').execSync('./stop.sh').exec; //it should stop it but it doesn't work!

    //Let's try with a test reply to Client A
    xmpp.send('pippoman@prova.it', 'stopped!'); //replies not sent!!!
});
```

Comment: Try adding some debugging code to see if the second shell.exec is called and if it returns or not.

Comment: I just removed the shell.exec and used the classic child_process in order to simplify the script (I think execSync is more famouse than the shelljs, right?)
None of the two calls seems working in "stop section". Time to debug, ok

Comment: can you call stop.sh from cli? Is it work? (maybe you need to set chmod +x ./stop.sh)

Comment: Yes, it works from cli (+x already set).